# Java For Loop to iterate 100 64 36 16 4 0 4 16 36 64 100 using a single variable

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration

I want to write a for loop in the format below, using only a single variable e. The (____) blank spaces are the only things I want changed. It should print out 100 64 36 16 4 0 4 16 36 64 100. I'm not sure how get it to reiterate after it reaches 0.:

```
for(_____________________)

    System.out.print(______________ + " ");

System.out.println();
```

This is what I tried so far. Is there a way to use only one variable e and still get it to reiterate through numbers it already used?:

```
for(int e = 10; e > 0; e -= 2)

    System.out.print(e * e + " ");

System.out.println();
```

Comment: Use the fact the negative numbers multiplied by each other are positive and use e >= -10.

Comment: +1, this is first homework question I see today with included attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the fact that e<sup>2</sup> = (-e)<sup>2</sup>, and stop when `e` is no longer greater than or equal to `-10`.

Comment: +1 @Diana In general, see if you can simplify your problem down to something that can be iterated over easily. Try to find a pattern, and try to use the properties of the numbers you are dealing with. For example, you already have the clear idea that you're working with squares. You also now recall that negative numbers multiply to produce positive numbers. Your list is now *10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10* with your choice of signs on each number. Well, *10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10* seems like a fine option to choose. Sometimes it also helps to work things out on paper first.

Comment: Thanks for the help! And thank you @JasonC for the explanation, it makes a lot more sense now. I didn't remember I could use negative numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact the negative numbers multiplied by each other are positive and use e >= -10.

```
    for (int e = 10; e > -11; e -= 2)
        System.out.print(e * e + " ");
    System.out.println();
```

I find it more readable to go negative to positive though. And it's generally a good idea to add the brackets in:

```
for (int e = -10; e < 11; e += 2) {
    System.out.print (e * e + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 1):

To take advantage of the fact that negative number multiplied to a negative number gives a positive number we can use your current solution. So as an example: e = 2 gives you 4 and e = -2 also gives you 4. Thus we can make a minor adjustment to your function:

```
for(e = 10; e >= -10; e -= 2)

    System.out.print(e * e + " ");

System.out.println();
```

That should give 100 64 36 16 8 4 0 4 8 16 36 64 100.

Comment: Point taken.. answer adjusted accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

> The competent programmer is fully aware of the strictly limited size of his own skull; therefore he approaches the programming task in full humility, and among other things he avoids clever tricks like the plague.
>
> -- Edsger W. Dijkstra

```
    for(int e : new int[]{ 100, 64, 36, 16, 4, 0, 4, 16, 36, 64, 100 }) {
        System.out.print(e + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Probably not the intended goal of the OP's assignment.